# Are we capable of deliberatly creating DNA from inorganic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, dna-rna

Good day
The  Miller–Urey experiment showed that organic compound can naturally form from inorganic substances. What i wish to know is this: Could we as humans deliberately create a DNA molecule starting with only inorganic substances?

Comment: Yes. You can make very many different types of organic compounds from carbon monoxide and hydrogen gas (syngas) . You then need, say, N2,  NO2,  NO or nitrates and phosphates to have all the elements you need. Not an easy thing to do though. No doubt the synthetic chemists can suggest very many other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we could.
It wouldn't be worth the effort since all the building blocks are available from biological sources, but if you really wanted to you could have a chemist prepare nucleotides from inorganic substances.
[Commercial labs](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_company_for_gene_synthesis) routinely build long strands of DNA from individual nucleotides. You can tell them what sequence you need and they will make it for you. There's a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gene_synthesis) on how it works.